# This logic problem seems to be missing info?

Tags: logic

This is a sample question for an employment related test I have to take:

Assume the first two statements are true:

1. Tom greeted Beth.
2. Beth greeted Dawn.
3. Tom did not greet Dawn.

If statement 3 is true then write (T) as your answer. If it is false then write (F) as your answer.

In the answer key this is listed as True. It doesn't seem to me like there is enough information to come to this conclusion. Am I missing something?

Comment: If there was really no more information, then yes this is just bogus (you usually greet more than one person...). Not really surprised if this is an employment test, though.

Comment: As a wild guess, I'll say that the person posing the problem imagined that people were entering a room one by one and that every person in the room  when $X$ enters greets $X$. But, as it stands, this is a terrible problem.

Comment: i think question designer has "transitive property" in his mind. but the amount of Vodka he/she consumed made his/her judgement questionable. unless the problem is not mentioned completely. are you sure you have wrote whole question completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to assume something about greeting that I don't get either.  A terrible problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can make sense of this is if the list of greetings is complete. That is we know there are no more greetings than those which are listed, though this would make the problem quite trivial.

In any other case there is either more context needed about the situation, or exactly how the "greeting" is supposed to be done.